# what are the differences among ARM Binaries, Linux Binaries nodejs and NodeSource Node.js Distributions

Tags: node.js, linux

What are the difference among ARM Binaries, Linux Binaries from the nodejs download (https://nodejs.org/en/download/) and NodeSource Node.js and io.js Binary Distributions (https://github.com/nodesource/distributions). Isn't ARM based machines using Linux? Why should I download Nodejs from https://github.com/nodesource/distributions#debian-and-ubuntu-based-distributions instead of https://nodejs.org/en/download/?

Comment: `Isn't ARM based machines using Linux?` Not the ones running Windows Phone OS. Also not the ones running embedded OSes like VXworks or mbed etc. But yes, in the case of node the Linux binaries are for x86, the ARM binaries are for Linux on ARM the Docker image is for Linux on x86 the rest describe themselves fairly well.

Comment: Thanks @slebetman, that exactly confuses me. But your answer clarifies the difference :)